# How to check spot instance termination-time

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

I am trying to understand how to use termination-time for spot instance. From this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/ I can unserstand when spot instance is marked for termination `wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time` will provide remaining time.

Anyone know how to implement or test this in real world scenario. for me its little difficult because spot termination can happened anytime.

So anyone has sample/ example if sot instance is marked for termination then sent an email something like that.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Configure `cron` to call some code that checks the URL. If the instance is marked for termination, then do whatever task you desire. This would normally involve saving work and copying information from the instance to a permanent location (eg Amazon S3).

Yes, it is hard to test because you cannot control the spot price, but you could test your code that is triggered when it happens.

See also: [Spot Instance Termination Notices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html)